# How to added font image to uilabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, truetype, uifont

I want to add font image to and UILabel. I added new TTF file to my resource folder which is **fontallo**. Added project info Fonts  **fontallo.ttf**.

Now I want to set those images which are inside the **fontallo**.

Please find the below images
[image: About the font image what it do have.]

```
[lbl_FontImage setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello" size:30]];
```

Unable to set those image to `UILabel`. Need suggestion to resolve it.

Comment: Is `[UIFont fontWithName:@"fontello" size:30]` `nil`? What's the text you put in your label (since there are characters)?

Comment: How to add custom font to your app : http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: after adding the custom font and trying to extract it    NSArray *fontFamilies = [UIFont familyNames];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < [fontFamilies count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *fontFamily = [fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *fontNames = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:[fontFamilies objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog (@"%@: %@", fontFamily, fontNames);
    }  its not showing fontello

Comment: @Now its working for me!!! I forgot to add to target into my Xcode Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have verified the font is loaded and set onto the label. If not you need to log all of the fonts loaded in the system, check it's there and find the correct font name to pass to `UIFont`.

You need to set the label text to a string containing the character you want. You generally need to know the character that the font is using, kind of like the location in the font file. Or, you can copy the character (from FontBook) directly into your code (though you might see a placeholder symbol in the code).

I'd say it's generally best not to copy and paste, but that's probably personal preference. Unicode is better to use. To get that you need a tool which will tell you the Unicode value of the character. Once you have that you can create the string and directly reference the character.

Comment: Thanks for replay.  I appreciate your inputs,  Since this fonts are unichar they are visible to my application,  Once i have added my own image font, like phone,mouse,car,bottle to TTF file.  which created by UI Team,  now iam add to my mobile application "Fonts Provided by application" and added that value "A" run the application it show A character, not the image which i expected.  but in font book its showing the character of image and even in text editor.

Comment: Did you check that your `UIFont` is not `nil`?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views on this question,   Its really help full,  I made a mistake forgot  to added to Xcode project target fontello.ttf.  Now its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your font names to your project's .plist file:

[image]